# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener is not working in fragment

Tags: android

Hi all I can get load data's and I can view but cant select item from that spinner list[this is my output page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v6k5.png)

Comment: add your code what you tried

Comment: show your code for better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  langeBtn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String selected = langeBtn.getSelectedItem().toString();
               // editor.putString("selected", selected);
               // editor.commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```